# Design bug when editing favorite tags

Tags: bug, design, tag-watching

The "Add" button is either truncated or altogether hidden when editing favorite tags:

- On Unix & Linux, English Language & Usage, Super User and Biology the right hand side border is not shown:

  [image]
- On Ask Ubuntu, it is much worse, I can't even see the word *Add* itself:

  [image]

I also checked on Science Fiction and Fantasy which has the old CSS style and there, the button is displayed correctly. I have the same issue on Chromium 45.0.2454.85 and Firefox 41.0 (slighlty worse on FF, I can only see about 2 pixels worth of the *A* in *Add*), both running on Debian.

---

<sub>I expect this is a duplicate but I can't seem to find one. Was there a recent change in the CSS style?</sub>